# List files more recent than another file using Windows batch

Tags: cmd

```
dir /b
```

lists the names of files in a directory. How do you list only the files more recent than a specified file, say foo.txt?

Comment: You have enough points to know how SO works. Show your code and people here are very helpful. If you do not have any code and need to hire a programmer, try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file can be used for this task:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
if not exist "%~1" goto :EOF
if exist "%~1\" goto :EOF

echo Files newer than %~nx1 in directory: %~dp1
echo/

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp1" /A-D /B /O-D') do (
    if /I "%~nx1" == "%%I" goto ExitLoop
    echo %%I
)

:ExitLoop
echo/
pause
```

The execution of the batch file is exited on batch file called

- with **no argument** or
- with an argument string which is **not** an existing file/directory or
- with an argument string which is an existing directory instead of a file.

The command **FOR** executes the command **DIR** in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background.

**DIR** outputs line by line

- just files because of `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- in bare format with file name + file extension only because of `/B`
- ordered reverse by last modification/write date which means newest file first and oldest file last because of `/O-D`
- all files including hidden files in the directory of specified file.

**FOR** captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and then processes the captured lines line by line with skipping empty lines which do not exist here.

**FOR** ignores by default lines starting with a semicolon. A file name can start with `;`. For that reason the end of line character is redefined using option `eol=|` from default `;` to vertical bar `|` as this character can't be used in a file name.

**FOR** splits by default each line up into substrings using space and tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable `I`. For that reason the list of delimiters is redefined with option `delims=` to an empty list of delimiters resulting in disabling line splitting to process correct also file names containing one or more spaces.

**DIR** outputs the file names sorted by date from newest to oldest. So inside the **FOR** loop a case-insensitive string comparison is used to check if the current file name is equal the specified file name. The loop is exited with a jump to a label below the loop if this condition becomes true. Otherwise the current file name is output to console.

Finally the batch file pause the execution of the batch file to be able to read the list in case of having started the batch file by double clicking on it.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains the batch file argument references.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`

**Note:** If one or more files have exactly the same last modification date of the specified file, it is unpredictable which of those files are also output by this code. One more **IF** condition would be necessary to exclude files with same file date as the specified file. The following **IF** condition can be used to exit the loop on file having same date/time **after** existing **IF** condition in body of **FOR** loop.

```
for %%J in ("%~dp1%%I") do if "%%~tJ" == "%~t1" goto ExitLoop
```

But this **IF** condition compares only file date/time without second. So it results also on exiting the loop if current file has same date, hour and minute, but a higher second value and is therefore also in real newer than the specified file on taking second into account which Windows command processor does not with this code.

Comment: Interesting! I was hoping to adapt it to compare files in different directories, but `DIR` sorts only within a directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy if you are willing to use PowerShell. It is less cumbersome when used in a .ps1 script, but it can be done in a .bat file script.

```
SET "SEARCHDIR=C:\src\t"
SET "REFFILE=C:\src\t\truename.bat"

powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path "%SEARCHDIR%" |" ^
        "Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-ChildItem -Path %REFFILE%).LastWriteTime }"
```

If you know the date to be used as the starting point, it can be put into the command.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path "%SEARCHDIR%" |" ^
        "Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge '2018-08-14' }"
```